# How to start xmonad?

Tags: gnome, window-manager, vmware, desktop-environments, xmonad

I am under `GNOME`, and a Ubuntu 11.10 as virtual machine, which does not enable 3D accelaration.

I just downloaded `xmonad` via software center.

I guess the first step is to replace the current window manager (`metacity`), and then set or learn the shortcut keys.

But when I launch `xmonad` in a terminal, that gives me:

```
/home/.../.xmonad/xmonad-x86_64-linux: executeFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  2 (X_ChangeWindowAttributes)
  Serial number of failed request:  7
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
```

Could anyone tell me how to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should choose the session "XMonad" from the login manager (LightDM by default).

Some useful keys:

<kbd>Mod</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> open a terminal
<kbd>Mod</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> launch gmrun
<kbd>Mod</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> quit xmonad

where <kbd>Mod</kbd> is the Win key.