# Anyone succeeded in Using Xmonad in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, xmonad

I have been trying hard to configure Xmonad on my Ubuntu 12.04.  Will appreciate if someone sheds some light on installation, configuration and if one could also share the relevant files used in configuration!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start xmonad?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/122639/how-to-start-xmonad)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/davidbrewer/xmonad-ubuntu-conf

This one works fine. I tried it myself. I think this is best for anyone who wants to do multi-tasking.

Comment: I tried this, it poses following problem:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/231201/audio-problem-with-xmonad

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3156991) might come in handy. Particularly for those wanting to quickly paste some commands and it will just work.